# How to find if ASP.net server control is loaded in DESIGN mode or not?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-controls

My ASP.net server control is giving me error: "Error Rendering Control". Below is the screenshot.
[image]

Runtime it is working as expected but at design time I am getting above error.

Comment: see msdn [Adding Design-Time Support to ASP.NET Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478960.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Here I have written a small function to determine whether control is loaded in Design View or Run time. Accordingly We can take decision whether to use HTTPContext or not.

```
public bool IsInDesignMode()
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current == null)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
```

--
Thanks
Deepak Rai